# Allow front end selection of time zone to change times on entries

Tags: channel-entries, timezone, localization

I have a series of entries all set to fixed time in the system (and they're all Eastern time). These times are displayed on the front end to the user. But I've been asked if it would be possible to localize the times on demand by the visitor - so like a simple dropdown that would allow them to select "pacific" and have the page refresh to pacific times for all entries AND have that setting carry with the user throughout their visit (I'm not fussy about a return visit).

Is this possible? There's no time zone parameter or anything in the entries loop so I'm struggling with what the simplest solution would be.

Comment: Have you considered using the converting from UTC to local time on the client side via Javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript